# How to take data from row from an SQL query and show it in column in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have the following design view in SSRS:

[image]

When previewed this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see the `Entity Name` appears twice for 'Group'. What I am looking to do is if there is many entries per entity put them in same row in different column, something like this:

[image]

I am currently using a table to display the data.

How do I achieve the result I am looking for?

Comment: Have you tried using matrix layout in SSRS ?

Comment: I tried but in Matrix only the first date group shows up and the rest doesn't!

Comment: I suggest you keep trying with matrix. Especially if there can be 3, 4, 5, 6 or more entities

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u can use a workaround ? I would first use a column named "Category". Using the Case function you can give a new name. After that you need the `order by` function. For example :

```
  ,CASE
    WHEN database.entityname like '%Group' THEN 'xx Group'
    WHEN database.entityname like '%ASX' THEN 'xx ASC'  

END as Category
```

then use "Category" in your table and not "Entity name".

This should make your table look like the following for example :

Last name - Category - Date of last credentialing - Credentialing expired

Same Name - xx Group - 10/01/2017 - 12/01/2017

Same Name - xx Group - 15/01/2017 - 22/02/2017

Same Name - xx ASC   - 12/02/2017 - 05/03/2017

It will not make your columns in a row, but they will be grouped together if u then use the `Order BY` function. Order by Last Name, Category,... If you have dates like yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would first add a partitioned Row Number eg

ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY [LastName] , [EntityName] ORDER BY [DateOfLastCredentialling] ) AS Column_Group

Then I would add a Column Group to the Tablix, using that new column.